# Which case is “über alle Maßen”?

Tags: expression, declension

> Über alle Maßen

I’m guessing from the form *Maßen* that it’s in the dative case. But then the adjective declension should be with the suffix *-en*, right?

So … why is it *alle* instead of *allen*? Or is this a special case I haven’t learnt yet …？

Comment: I agree with that assessment, i.e. accusative.

Comment: I feel like saying "see it as a frozen historic form", but this might not be enough here ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The word *Maßen* is the plural of the archaic feminine noun *[Maße](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masze).*

In *über alle Maßen* it is the accusative case.

Comment: All the dictionaries I looked in say Maße is the plural... you mean Maßen is another older version of plural form?

Comment: @Reane These are two different words: _[das Maß](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masz_Messgeraet_Einheit_Grad)_ (plural: _die Maße_) and _[die Maße](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masze)_ (plural: _die Maßen_)